# [Angular 6 ]How can I reload the same child component page in live server?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-routing

I would like to reload to the same page in live server(cPanel).

Atm i have no issue at 
http://localhost:4200/funding, but when i tried to reload the page at
http://something/np/dist/thesandbox/funding the following error occurs.

**Main Page:**
http://something/np/dist/thesandbox/

**Child Page:**
http://something/np/dist/thesandbox/funding

What would the best solution for the following error:

*Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.*

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
...........
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent},
{ path: 'funding', component: FundingComponent},
..........
@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `hash` in your routing module like this :

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }),
```

instead of

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
```